# jqueryui accordian losing bindings on Knockout visible change

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js

I have a knockout viewmodel which contains children viewmodels. When a selection is made on a navbar, the body changes to whichever of the children was selected.

When the parent VM is init'd (after ko bindings), it calls init on the children VM, which in turn create the appropriate jqueryui bindings.

The problem is when the parent switches between selected nav selections, hiding the div's of the different VM children. When you switch back to them, the jqueryui bindings are gone.

Anyone know what is going on here? I thought Knockoutjs's visible attribute merely flipped the css visible attr of the parent container. Why would jqueryui lose its bindings from that?

http://jsfiddle.net/Gehh9/

Comment: your code doesn't work at all, http://jsfiddle.net/bbmxD/ I was excited about the possibilities of this question, but I don't see you able to present a bit of working code to start from.

Comment: Oh man, my very first post here and already with the negative points. I fixed the bug in the example code and now it "works" as described, ie it breaks after selecting the second option then switching back to the first. Here is the updated link: http://jsfiddle.net/Gehh9/

Comment: no worries, put your jsfiddle in your post with an edit and I can remove the downvote :)

Comment: OK, looks like I got the post so that it makes some sort of sense and has the working link. Maybe now someone will know the answer. So weird for jqueryui to lose its bindings because a parent tag was hidden.

Comment: I have discovered it has something to do with the child VM. When I move the jquery code to the parent VM, it works without issue. Interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a simple binding a while back that you can use instead of 
`with`. Here's your example using the `withlight` binding:

http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/Gehh9/5/

Answer (score 0):

It's because of your **with** binding.

The **with** binding (along with **foreach**) control the data binding context of elements beneath. Your **visible** binding changes the visibility of the elements, which is fine, but because it's bundled alongside the **with** binding, the elements get re-rendered.

This *might* be a bug in Knockout, since really you don't want the elements removed from the DOM in the first place. You may want to report this in the Knockout mailing list.

Here's [an updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gehh9/4/) that skips the **with** binding, and you'll notice that it works properly, even with the visible binding still present.